# Add to <body> tag of a cakePHP app

Tags: templates, cakephp, onload

I have an app where I need to call some JS in the onLoad event of the BODY tag of two forms.  However, I can't find how to modify the tag for just them.  Does anyone know?

Frank

Comment: Do you have app/views/layouts/default.ctp defined? If not, Cake uses the one in cake/ instead. You can add your own layout, and append your onload there if you like. Here's a link: http://www.geekdaily.net/2007/07/27/javascript-windowonload-is-bad-mkay/.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**inkedmn** certainly has provided the right answer for this case, but in general, you can "hand information up" like this:

(in views/controller/view.ctp)

```
$this->set('bodyAttr', 'onload="something"');
```

(in views/layouts/default.ctp)

```
<?php
    if (isset($bodyAttr)) {
        $bodyAttr = " $bodyAttr";
    } else {
        $bodyAttr = null;
    }
?>
<body<?php echo $bodyAttr; ?>>
```

I often use it like this to add extra classes to a "top level element":

```
<?php
    if (!isset($docClass)) {
        $docClass = null;
    }
?>
<div id="doc" class="<?php echo $docClass; ?>">
```

Comment: I do prefer setting values in the controller.

Comment: For something like classes I don't, as they're purely view-layer related.

Answer (score 5):

You don't need to modify the body tag to have Javascript execute when the page loads. You could just include something like this in your layout where appropriate:

(jQuery)

```
$("body").load(
    function(){
        // do stuff when the body element is loaded.
    }
);
```

Or, if you want to have the code execute when the document.ready event fires:

```
$(function(){
        // do stuff when the document is ready
    }
);
```

Or, if you don't want to use jQuery, you could do something like this:

```
function doStuff(){
    // whatever you want to happen when the load completes
}

window.onload = dostuff;
```

Good luck - and please clarify your question if this answer isn't satisfactory.

Answer (score 0):

I do the following:

We apply $ bodyLoad in my body

```
<body <? = (isset ($ bodyLoad)? 'onload = \''. $ bodyLoad.' \'',''); ?> >
```

Already in my [action]. Ctp, I do the following:

```
<? php $ this-> set ('bodyLoad', 'field.focus ();');?>
```

If you want you can also put this code in the controller.

Good luck