# CakePHP selected state for navigation links

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm building a portfolio website using CakePHP that has a navigation like so:

```
<nav id="nav">
        <ul>
            <li><?php echo $html->link('Home', '/', array('title' => 'Home')); ?></li>
            <li><?php echo $html->link('Portfolio', '/portfolio', array('title' => 'Portfolio')); ?>
                <ul>
                    <li><?php echo $html->link('Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit', '/portfolio', array('title' => 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit')); ?></li>
                    <li><?php echo $html->link('Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit', '/portfolio', array('title' => 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit')); ?></li>
                    <li><?php echo $html->link('Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit', '/portfolio', array('title' => 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit')); ?></li>
                    <li><?php echo $html->link('Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit', '/portfolio', array('title' => 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit')); ?></li>
                    <li><?php echo $html->link('Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit', '/portfolio', array('title' => 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit')); ?></li>
                    <li><?php echo $html->link('Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit', '/portfolio', array('title' => 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit')); ?></li>
                    <li><?php echo $html->link('Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit', '/portfolio', array('title' => 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit')); ?></li>
                    <li><?php echo $html->link('Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit', '/portfolio', array('title' => 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit')); ?></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><?php echo $html->link('About me', '/about', array('title' => 'About me')); ?></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

However I would like to add a class of selected to the links when a user is on that page OR within the nested page of it. So for example if they were on a portfolio item then BOTH the item link and the portfolio would have `class="selected"` on the `<li>`.

Anyone ever done anything like this with CakePHP? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Instead of adding a "selected" class to the `<li>`, you might want to add an `id` attribute on the `<body>` tag instead.  This solution would be easier to cascade for pages within a specific section that may not adhere to a strict, predictable URL pattern.  You could have a default for each controller, etc.

This answer explains how to easily add an `id` attribute to the `<body>` tag in CakePHP: [Add to <body> tag of a cakePHP app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1931144/add-to-body-tag-of-a-cakephp-app/1931737#1931737)

Otherwise, there are a few menu and navigation view helpers floating around.  I found this one here: http://www.solitechgmbh.com/2008/06/06/menu-highlighting-with-cakephp-12/

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit of a combination of CakePHP and "normal" html/php, but it works for me in my CakePHP site.

```
<a href="/portfolio" <? if($this->params['controller'] == "portfolio")
     echo 'class="selected"'; ?>>PORTFOLIO</a>
```

Or, if you need to check more than just the controller, you can check the action too.

```
<a href="/pages/about" <? if($this->params['controller'] == "pages"
     && $this->params['action'] == "about")
     echo 'class="selected"'; ?>>ABOUT</a>
```

Comment: What about pages? such as `/pages/about`

Comment: Then you check `$this->patams['controller']` and `$this->params['action']`